# Navigate back to the previously selected tab in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have one page with dynamically created tabs as when required. In page 2 i have a some data that needs to be attached to the page 1 selected tab and i am able to do that. But when i am trying to navigate to the page 2 i could go only to page 2  with `windows.location.replace("page2")`.

If i want to go to the that selected tab as well how to do that?

```html
<div ng-repeat="t in ticketdata" class="time-tab-adspace" ng-class="{'tab-align-center':ticketsdata.length==2}">
    <a class="nav-people-tab text-hover" data-toggle="tab" ng-class="{'nav-people-tab-hover in':'ticket'+seltab=='ticket'+t.ticket_code}" ng-click="selecttab(t)"  data-target="#ticket{{$index}}">{{t.name}}</a>
</div>
```

Is there any way like store the details of selected items and when redirecting to page 2 just redirect to tab (which ever selected)??

Comment: Please show all relevant code. Really not clear what you are doing. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is to set the selected tab as query string parameter. So you will have for navigation:

```
window.location.replace("/page2?tab=2)"
```

And in the controller check for the query string tab value and activate the corresponding tab.

Comment: That will not work in my case. Can you please tell me any other way

Comment: The URL of the page will not change if you click on individual tabs.Same should happen here also (i mean in my case)